# Do we need to configure the custom HOST header on Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure

I am not sure what else I can add here. On one hand, this header is added automatically when navigating to a URL from a browser. So, it could be a logic choice for the traffic manager to add it too automatically.

Anyway, should we configure it explicitly?

Comment: What problem are trying to solve?

Comment: Good question. No problem really. It is just that the terraform code I received from someone configures it and I wonder why. Unfortunately, I cannot ask that person.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only place in traffic manager configuration where you can enter headers is healthcheck configuration, so if the endpoint you use for healthchecks requires a specific Host header, you can put it there.

Comment: So, if my health check does not require anything, then there is no real need to specify any custom headers, correct?